# How to clear IOS simulator memory cache

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

In my ionic app I set tokens in local memory:

```
 set: function(key, value) {
        $window.localStorage[key] = value;
      },
```

This works fine. When i ran the app in ios simulator for the first time.. it detected that there was nothing in the localstorage and behaved accordigly. However everytime I run the app in the simulator now.. it always detects the token . I would like to clear the localStorage in the IOS simulator for my app.

Whats the process to do this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just treat your simulator like a real iPhone. Click and hold one of the icons so they all wiggle. Then delete your installed app. This will remove its saved data.

Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (like the home button on the phone) to exit wiggle mode.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. Removing the app and clearing local storage are two different things.

Comment: La idea es limpiar el almacenamiento, no desinstalar la aplicación. Aun así no funciona desinstalando la aplicación, los datos persisten

Comment: that just hides it

Answer (score 19):

Open the simulator. Open the iOS Simulator, in the top Menu bar: `Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings...`. This will clear the whole simulator to default settings as well as remove any apps you have installed and their associated stored data.

Comment: While this works, I prefer the method in my answer because it only erases the data for one app, leaving everything else intact.

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for. I didn't want to delete all 50+ apps on the simulator by hand.

Comment: These days, the option is located in `Top menu bar -> Device -> Erase All Content and Settings...`. 

& it worked, thanks!